# What to do after standardizing a data set using a t-score if I want to be able to compare it to a value?

Tags: t-test

I am not sure if what I am doing is correct, but here goes:
I want to compare the X big and X small, but they are different in actual sizes. How do I standardize it? Is it by getting each of the sample's (30 samples) z-score?
[image]
And after I standardize it, how can I compare it to their respective actual size?

I am truly lost on how to proceed, so I would appreciate even a point in the right direction (what to look for). Thank you!

Comment: Why not just compute their ratio X big / X small?

Comment: Thank you for your input! Sorry, I didn't provide enough information. I'm looking for the closeness of the X big to the actual size 50.00 and the X small to the actual size 11.00. Then compare which one of them is closer to their actual value. My teacher said I should standardize the data. So far, I computed for their z-scores to do so, but I'm stuck because I don't know how to compare those z-scores to the actual value.

Comment: X and Y are different methods of measuring. They measured 30 samples each. I'm trying to determine the accuracy of the method as affected by the size of the objects they've measured: big and small.

Comment: This is just a mock bar chart by the way!